# How to custom user table in MVC 5 using identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I want to using identity technology in MVC 5 with custom table , but i don't know how to do it . For example, my [user] table is

```
id primary key identity(1,1),
username  nvarchar(50),
password nvarchar(50),
email varchar(100),
address nvarchar(100)
.... some information
```

how i can do ? thank for any help !

Comment: You might want to take a look at this : http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity There are a lot of resource in there to get you started.

Comment: so many things i need to learn , thank u :D

Comment: This post helped me alot in the beginning.  http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1
I think you might be more interested in Part two of this series, but Part one is worth a read as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally , I did it ! 
if another have problem like me please read some links

> [Trying to change table names in ASP.NET Identity 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749021/trying-to-change-table-names-in-asp-net-identity-2-0)
>   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796940/Understanding-Using-and-Customizing-ASP-NET-Identi

You need using code first migrations for your model and update it using package console command
**update-database**
.